# Elasticsearch: search elements outside a range

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have data stored in elastic with a year_start and year_end integer values.

Then, I use a "year" to query elements.

My goal is to search elements that are within a "year".

When I need to search elements in a "year" that is within that range, I can do it ok using:

```
{
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "year_start": {
                                "lte": year
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "year_end": {
                                "gte": year
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
         }
}
```

However, I can't get elements that are NOT in that range. I tried this:

```
{
        "query": {
            "must_not": {
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "year_start": {
                                "lte": year
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "year_end": {
                                "gte": year
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
         }
}
```

My *quessing* is that it filter each of both conditions separately, and it's not using both at the same time. Something like, "first I exclude everything up to year, and then later I exclude everything from year", instead of the expected "exclude every element that matches both conditions at the same time".

**[EDIT]**
Based on the answer received, here's an example of what I'm trying, but still not working. It should get all elements for year 2022 and not with year 2023:

```
DELETE test

PUT test/_bulk?refresh
{"index": {}}
{"year_start": "2022", "year_end": "2022" }
{"index": {}}
{"year_start": "2023", "year_end": "2024" }
{"index": {}}
{"year_start": "2021", "year_end": "2025" }
{"index": {}}
{"year_start": "2016", "year_end": "2020" }

# All ranges that include 2022 and not 2023
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "year_start": {
              "lte": 2022
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "year_end": {
              "gte": 2022
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "year_start": {
              "gt": 2023
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "year_end": {
              "lt": 2023
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple possible solutions here. If you store the range boundaries as separate fields you can use range queries:

```
DELETE test

PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "year_start": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "year_end": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/_bulk?refresh
{"index": {}}
{"year_start": 2022, "year_end": 2022 }
{"index": {}}
{"year_start": 2023, "year_end": 2024 }
{"index": {}}
{"year_start": 2021, "year_end": 2025 }
{"index": {}}
{"year_start": 2016, "year_end": 2020 }

# All ranges that include 2022
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "year_start": {
              "lte": 2022
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "year_end": {
              "gte": 2022
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

# All ranges that don't include 2022
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "year_start": {
              "gt": 2022
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "year_end": {
              "lt": 2022
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

# All ranges that don't include 2023
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "year_start": {
              "gt": 2023
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "year_end": {
              "lt": 2023
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

# All ranges that include 2022 but don't include 2023
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "year_start": {
                    "lte": 2022
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "year_end": {
                    "gte": 2022
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "year_start": {
                    "gt": 2023
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "year_end": {
                    "lt": 2023
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The last query can be simplified by moving the must clause from the first inner query into the outer query, but I left it as is for clarity.

An alternative solution for storing and searching ranges is using range type:

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "year_range": {
        "type": "integer_range"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/_bulk?refresh
{"index": {}}
{"year_range":{ "gte":  2022, "lte": 2022 }}
{"index": {}}
{"year_range":{ "gte":  2023, "lte": 2024 }}
{"index": {}}
{"year_range":{ "gte":  2021, "lte": 2025 }}
{"index": {}}
{"year_range":{ "gte":  2016, "lte": 2020 }}


# All ranges that include 2022
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term" : {
      "year_range" : {
        "value": 2022
      }
    }
  }
}

# All ranges that don't include 2022
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "year_range": {
              "value": 2022
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @imotov for your answer! Anyway, 2 clarifications here: the year fields are stored as integers, not dates, so it's easier and I avoid date challenges; and the second is that the fields I use for start and end years are different, so I think I can't use 1 single date with both "gte" and "lte" as shown.

Comment: It's a good practice to put mapping together with your question and explain what you are trying to achieve so people who are trying to help you don't waste their time.

Comment: Sorry, I'll have that in mind next time.

Comment: Your answer worked ok. I must use *should* instead of *must_not*. And I'll investigate this integer_range alternative, that looks even better for my goals.

Comment: Not sure why, but after some tests, it's not working. Using _should_ instead of _must_not_ .

Comment: Can you post example of what doesn't work?

Comment: Hi! I modified the original post, and added an [EDIT] section at the end, where I show an example trying to combine both options in one.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't notice that in your example `year_start` and `year_end` are strings and copied them over. I fixed it in my example now. They should be integers.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the string vs integer isn't a problem. What I'm trying to, is to combine your 2 first responses "All ranges that include 2022" and "All ranges that don't include 2023" as 1 single search for "All elements that include 2022 and don't include 2023". Does it make sense?

Comment: I see. The simplest solution is to just use two boolean queries as two must clauses of another boolean query. All must clauses can be pushed to the outer query as an optimization, but you don't really have to do that since elasticsearch will do that for you. I added an example.